# empty key while using dictread

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am using dictread to read a cvs file. my problem is that for some files I get an empty key. I only have 6 keys:below are my code and file:

```
from datetime import datetime
from math import sqrt, exp, log
from csv import DictReader
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

train = '/Users/mas/Documents/workspace/Avito/input/minitrain.csv'

for t,row in enumerate(DictReader(open(train))):
    pass

print row
```

this is my output

```
{'': None, 'SearchID': '4', 'IsClick': None, 'HistCTR': '', 'AdID': '24129570', 'Position': '2', 'ObjectType': '2'}
```

this is my cvs file

```
SearchID,AdID,Position,ObjectType,HistCTR,IsClick,
2,11441863,1,3,0.001804,0,
2,22968355,7,3,0.004723,0,
3,212187,7,3,0.029701,0,
3,34084553,1,3,0.004300,0,
3,36256251,2,2,,,
4,2073399,6,1,,,
4,6046052,7,1,,,
4,17544913,8,1,,,
4,20653823,1,3,0.003049,0,
4,24129570,2,2,,,
```

Whay am  I getting an empty key?!

Comment: Your CSV is not valid. The number of commas in each line should be the same as the header.

Comment: On the header, it seems you have an empty key at the end of the line. If you remove the comma it might help. Then you will need to fix it in all lines.

Comment: Your suggestion fixed the problem. But I am surprised, don't I need a comma to separate the lines in a cvs file? @Medi

Comment: @MAS thats what the newline character is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set fieldnames when read csv file:
`DictReader(open(train), fieldnames=('SearchID', 'AdID', 'Position', 'ObjectType', 'HistCTR', 'IsClick',))`

You could write your own DictReader based on `DictReader`:

```
class MyDictReader():
    def __init__(self, f, fieldnames=None, dialect='excel', *args, **kwrags):
        self.reader = csv.reader(f, dialect, *args, **kwrags)
        self._fieldnames = fieldnames
        if self._fieldnames is None:
            try:
                self._fieldnames = next(self.reader)
            except StopIteration:
                pass

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        d = {}
        row = self.reader.next()
        for index, fieldname in enumerate(self._fieldnames):
            if fieldname:
                d[fieldname] = row[index]
        return d
```

And after using it:

```
for t, row in enumerate(MyDictReader(open(train))):
    pass    
print row
```

You will get output without empty key:

```
{'SearchID': '4', 'IsClick': '', 'HistCTR': '', 'AdID': '24129570', 'Position': '2', 'ObjectType': '2'}
```

Comment: I still get am empty key:this is my output:{'SearchID': '4', 'IsClick': '', 'HistCTR': '', 'AdID': '24129570', 'Position': '2', None: [''], 'ObjectType': '2'}